# Difficulty to understand linked list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I found this C++ linked list implementation in Geeks for Geeks. For the code  [Click here](https://codeshare.io/5QoRAm)

Here from line no. `16->22` it is  written

```
Node *head = NULL;
Node *second = NULL;
Node *last = NULL;    
head = new Node();
second = new Node();
last = new Node();
```

I understand

- Three pointers are initialized with value `NULL` and then later three
  instances of the class are created.

But what I don't understand is

- Where the class objects are created and
- From where the pointers are getting the addresses to point to.
- And if I keep any data in private how to access it later then in this implementation because `.` operator is giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where the class objects are created

The allocating `new`-expression acquires the memory from the free store.

> From where the pointers are getting the addresses to point to.

The `new`-expression returns the pointer to the object that it created.

> how to access it later

By indirecting through the pointer using an indirection operator.

Comment: Assume that I have put the int data of class node in private and created a function in public named push_data which accepts a int in arguments and modifies the private data.

Comment: then should I write like this: *head.data(1);

Comment: @SoumalyaBhattacharya You can access private members in member functions.

Comment: Then like *head.push_data(1)?? Sorry for annoying you but its getting on my nerves now